# python subprocess.Popen capture lots of output

Tags: python, subprocess

I am calling subprocess.Popen from a python script and then calling communicate

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmds, shell=shell, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE)  

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

The problem with this is that stdout is buffered and will only capture a certain number of characters.

The question is, how can I get the full stdout and the full stderr of the process that I spawn?

Comment: You should get all of processes' out & err. Can you throw samples?

Comment: I was referencing a part of the documentation


http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html  

Note

The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.  

The outputs are compiles that are too big to post on line I put examples at 

http://eng.utah.edu/~rweber/python_out.txt

Comment: You will get all the output as long as you do not run out of system memory (or get an error that maximal length of python string is exceeded)

Comment: I will give it another attempt and see if maybe an error was thrown, but I am getting a lot of output.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points.

If you are using **PIPE** for **stdout/stderr** and the **Popened** process starts to write large amount of data, and in your process you aren't reading either **stdout/stderr** then the ***Popened process would block***. Which is ***kind of*** stated as

```
Note

Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. As the pipes are not being read in the current process, the child process may block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer.
```

Regarding the other note which you pointed. That is applicable only if you Popen with **stdout=None,stderr=None**. In that case all of the **Popened process'** out/err will be stored in memory.